# setting the variable of js function from within htm

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple function that warns the user when they are about to close out of a web page. I am using the window.onbeforeonload function is javascript. What I am doing is that, I set a variable to false because of the evil window.onbeforeonload function.

```
function funky() {
var submitFormOkay = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (submitFormOkay == false) {
        return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
    }
}
}
```

In my html, this is what I am doing

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="submitFormOkay = true;">
```

My question however is that I need a way to fire the function funky(). 
I know I could use an onclick but if I do what is going to set the value of submitFormOkay.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make `submitFormOkay` a parameter of the function `funky`, and just call it with the given parameter?

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="funky(true);">
```

And in the JS file:

```
function funky(submitFormOkay) {
     window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (submitFormOkay == false) {
           return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but `var submitFormOkay = false;` needs to be outside of the `function funky` otherwise it will overwrite

Comment: I was thinking about that but was not sure whether it was going to work. Thanks, I will give that a try.

Comment: @tawheed You certainly can pass parameters to your functions via `onclick`. I don't know why you *need* to, but I don't know what else calls `funky`.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your HTML, I'd do this instead:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (function(w) {
    w.submitFormOkay = false;
    return function() {
        if (!w.submitFormOkay) {
            return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
        }
    };
})(window);
```

​A problem with ngmiceli's solution is that `window.onbeforeunload`'s callback never gets defined until the user is okay to leave the page.

Comment: So what would be the 'w' value that I pass in my html? Would it be the value that I would like to set? e.g true or false

Comment: I agree that such *may be* a problem, but its a problem that existed in the OP's provided code. I was merely answering the asked question while trying to preserve the structure given, assuming the OP had a reason for doing it that way

Comment: @tawhead Don't worry about it. It's just the window object to make `submitFormOkay` global. You don't need to change anything in your HTML.

Comment: @tawheed He is calling the very function after defining it, where you see `(window)`. That's what is being passed into `w`. Rather, in this solution you would alter the value of `submitFormOkay` in the window and not call `funky`, just attempt to leave the page

Comment: Thanks to you all for the feedback :-)